# Find the index of columns containing more than 5 NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

I want to subset a dataframe and extract only the columns that contain 5 or more NA values.

```
data.frame(A = rep(1, 10), B = c(rep(2,5), rep(3,5)), D = rep(5, 10), E = c(rep(1,2), rep(NA,6), rep(6,2)), F = c(rep(NA,2), rep(2,8)))

   A B D  E  F
1  1 2 5  1 NA
2  1 2 5  1 NA
3  1 2 5 NA  2
4  1 2 5 NA  2
5  1 2 5 NA  2
6  1 3 5 NA  2
7  1 3 5 NA  2
8  1 3 5 NA  2
9  1 3 5  6  2
10 1 3 5  6  2
```

So in this example I want to have the index of the column "E".

My original dataset has about 3000 columns, so speed is more or less important.

I have been trying to do this with `sum(is.na)` and `filter_if(any_vars)` but all to no avail..

Comment: The answers given are good, but since you mention extracting the actual columns (not just their index/name), here's how (if it isn't obvious from the answers): `df[colSums(is.na(df)) > 5]` or with `dplyr`: `df %>% 
  select_if(~sum(is.na(.)) > 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on logical matrix (`is.na(df1)`), get the index with `which` and extract the `names`

```
names(which(colSums(is.na(df1)) >= 5))
#[1] "E"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `ColSums` with `is.na`

```
names(df)[colSums(is.na(df))>5]
[1] "E"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
which(unlist(lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) > 5)))
4
```